# Power BI - how to create measure based on conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a base table 'Orders' with a column OrderNo, this column is being used in a visual.

I have another table 'Operations' with columns: OrderNo, OperationNo, TimeTaken (this is just a numeric column). This table is related to base table with OrderNo. Please note that one OrderNo can have multiple OperationNo.

I want to add a column to my visual 'TimeRemaining', which takes all OperationNo (from Operations table) for an OrderNo and sums the TimeTaken column.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If tables have relation you can just create measure in order:
CALCULATE(SUM('Operations'[TimeTaken]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Power bi groups the data in a visual automatically.
2. if they are linked you can make a calculated column in Orders

```
TimeRemaining =
SUM ( OperationNo[TimeTaken] )
```

3. if you want a it in the Operations specifically then:

```
TimeRemaining =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Operations[TimeTaken] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Operations, Operations[OrderNo] )
)
```

NOTE.
the first is for a calculated column in Orders table
the second one is for the Operations table.